# Why does changing display: block to float: left make this layout work?

Tags: css, css-float, block

So, I've managed to make this CSS work, but I'm not 100% sure why it does. I know that's the classic programmer's scenario. I'd like to know why it does, though, so that I can get better.

Here are the two JSfiddle cases (they're exactly the same but with one line different):

[With display:block](http://jsfiddle.net/velocirabbit/9mg9fphy/)

[With float:left](http://jsfiddle.net/velocirabbit/kf23o9h3/)

As you can see, the important line of CSS:

```
.name::before {
    content: '';
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
    float: left; /* OR -display: block;- */
    height: 22px; width: 100%;
    margin-top: -22px; margin-left: -11px;
    padding: 0 0px 0 22px;
}
```

With display:block, the pseudo-element matches the width of the main element (including the borders and padding. However, with float:left, the pseudo-element actually extends the width of the main element; if you change the padding-left to 11px, the increased width disappears, but the ::before stops short and doesn't include the main element's padding+border. This makes me think that inline elements affect other elements that it doesn't share a line with, as long as they're in the same container. Is that right?

Oddly, if you make change the padding to padding: 0 11px, it doesn't extend the right side of the ::before to the edge of the main element like I thought it would. Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: In both your fiddles, the purple element is exactly as wide as the label (even though they have different lengths). But since you are using `width: 100%` this is hardly a surprise.

Comment: The width: 100% makes them as long as the text in both cases, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is:

```
display: block;
```

only display the element in block,

while

```
float: left;
```

does push the element to the very left of its parents.

If you want to have all the elements to be in one line, 
try to use `display: inline;`